# neo4j: lucene ParseException: cannot parse 'bbox'

Tags: neo4j, lucene, cypher, neo4j-spatial

I am using ruby with neography backed by neo4j with spatial extension. 
The following error occured:

> org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'bbox:[11.6,11.4,47.1,48.2]': Encountered \" \"]\" \"] \"\" at line 1, column 25.\nWas expecting one of:\n    \"TO\" ...\n     ...\n     ...\n    " (Neography::BadInputException)

**This is the query:**

```
start n = node:road_nodes('bbox:[11.6,11.4,47.1,48.2]') return n
```

The same error occurs if I put the query in the web-frontend of neo4j:
(Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure)

with the error-message like above:

> org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'bbox:[11.6,11.4,47.1,48.2]': Encountered " "]" "] "" at line 1, column 25.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       "TO" ...
>        ...
>        ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer to my own question:**

This error occurs, when there is no spatial index.

In my case I forgot to create the spatial index after I reset the whole database.

So the solution to this "parse error" is to simply create the spatial index.